# SQL Server : sum two columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL statement which shows me transactions from a Point Of Sale system. I would like to calculate the total sum of `(MoneyIn - MoneyOut)` columns but is a bit beyond me and show this as a single value.  I am sure its a simple mod to this.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime;
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime;
DECLARE @SearchTerm NVARCHAR(200);

SET @SearchTerm = '%widget1%'
SET @StartDate = '2018-05-01 00:00:00'
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(month, 1, @StartDate)

SELECT TOP (500)
    t.TransactionDate,
    t.MoneyIn,
    t.MoneyOut,
    t.Description,
    p.PaymentMethodName,
    t.TransactionRef,
    c.SalesItems,
    COUNT(*) AS Occurrences
FROM
    Transactions t
LEFT JOIN 
    Tills tl ON t.TillId = tl.TillId
INNER JOIN 
    PaymentMethods p ON t.PaymentMethodId = p.PaymentMethodsID
INNER JOIN 
    Membership m ON t.UserId = m.UserId
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT 
         STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(tp.Description AS VARCHAR(100))
                FROM TransactionsPosLines tp
                WHERE t.TransactionId = tp.TransactionId
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS SalesItems) c
WHERE
    t.TransactionDate >= @StartDate
    AND t.TransactionDate <= @EndDate
    AND (t.PaymentTypeId = 1)
    AND SalesItems LIKE @SearchTerm
GROUP BY
    t.TransactionDate,
    t.MoneyIn,
    t.MoneyOut,
    t.Description,
    p.PaymentMethodName,
    t.TransactionRef,
    m.Username,
    c.SalesItems
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(*) DESC
```

Output:

```
2018-05-01 17:23:23.243 9.99    0.00    Sale - Card Card    Shop Sale   Grab n Go item  1
2018-05-08 13:15:04.577 10.00   -0.01   Sale - Cash Total: 9.99 Cash    Shop Sale   Grab n Go item  1
2018-05-10 14:08:47.120 7.99    0.00    Sale - Card Card    Shop Sale   Grab n Go item,Discount 1
```

and I want to show:

Total Sales: 27.97

(Sum of MoneyIn - Sum of MoneyOut)

Comment: Are you trying to consolidate these three records or add an additional field?

Comment: @DanielMarcus I am trying to condsolidate.. simply want to sum up the columns for MoneyIn - MoneyOut and have a value for this?

Comment: so just select  sum(MoneyIn)-sum(MoneyOut) from your final result set then

Comment: @DanielMarcus I did try this, but let me try again...

Comment: remove moneyin and moneyout from the group by and then sum(moneyin) - sum(moneyout) as moneytotal

Comment: @Andrew yes, this was the solution thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that this question has an answer

(edit: added the actual SQL I used to resolve this which gave the single result I was looking for), thanks for help:

```
Select top (10000)
    sum(t.MoneyIn) - sum(t.MoneyOut) as 'moneytotal'
From
    Transactions t
    LEFT JOIN  Tills tl
    ON t.TillId = tl.TillId
    INNER JOIN PaymentMethods p
    ON t.PaymentMethodId = p.PaymentMethodsID
    INNER JOIN Membership m
    On t.UserId = m.UserId
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT STUFF(
        (SELECT ',' + CAST(tp.Description AS VARCHAR(100))
        FROM
        TransactionsPosLines tp
        WHERE t.TransactionId = tp.TransactionId
        FOR XML PATH(''))
        ,1,1,'') as SalesItems) c
Where
    t.TransactionDate >= @StartDate
    AND t.TransactionDate <= @EndDate
        AND (t.PaymentTypeId = 1)
        and SalesItems LIKE @SearchTerm

        Order By
  count(*) Desc

  GO
```